# Constraint layout packed chain + dimension ratio, incorrect height

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have the following layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="32dp">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/icon_guide_start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".2"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/icon_guide_end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".8"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="600dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/icon_guide_start"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/icon_guide_end"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/message"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/action"
        tools:text="Nothing to see here"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/action"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/message"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:text="Reload"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The `icon` should consume 60% of the screen up to 600dp and have an aspect ration of 1:1. Next (below it) I want to have a message and an action. When running this layout with constraint layout 1.0.2 The `icon` view's height is computed to 0. If I remove the chain style `packed`, then the icon is the right size, but the views are no longer centered on the screen. I could wrap these in a vertical LinearLayout and center that, but then I lose the ability of the `message` to be wider than the `icon`.

Is this a bug in the constraint layout library? Is there a way around this?

Comment: https://medium.com/@sasanksunkavalli/android-constraintlayout-layout-constraintdimensionratio-33bd2293f34c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layout looks like it works with `ConstraintLayout` 1.1.0-beta3. At least it looks like this:

[image]

If this is what you are expecting then it is fixed in the later non-production version. See [this documentation](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/10/constraintlayout-110-beta-3-is-now.html) related to the beta3 release. It mentions a fix to a "ratio in chain" bug fix that may be this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time playing around with your layout. I think you've found a set of constraints the system solves in an unexpected way. I couldn't find a way to work around your problem, though I hesitate to cry *bug* just yet.

Some interesting observations:

- The layout "worked" for me if I removed the max width constraint
- If I remove the aspect ratio constraint and change the chain style to `spread`, the bounds of the image view grow to consume all available height
- If I remove the aspect ratio constraint and change the max width to `100dp`, the bounds of the image view change to 100x0 (as opposed to 0x0)

This leads me to believe that the `packed` chain style and the `H,1:1` aspect ratio are "fighting" with each other to determine the dimensions of your view. Assuming that `packed` means "make each view as short as possible", the system can successfully satisfy all constraints by setting the view's dimensions to 0x0.